# How to get better results with displacement?

Tags: displacement

I am adding displacement map with hard edges to an object after subdivision.

[image]

but the result is far from satisfactory.

Is it possible to make edges smoother and more refined?
Is it possible to add second subdivision after displacement map?
What is the best way to apply displacement?

[image]

Comment: Displacement needs topology, so I'm not sure you can can avoid subdivisions, particularly in the case of sharp pattern like the one you're using

Comment: I am not trying to remove subdivision but to get better results with it and here is my second question: how to add subdivision after shader displacement?

Comment: what I meant is that I'm not sure there's any other solution than subdividing even more, which doesn't seem a good idea giving the amount of polygons you will end up with, I may be wrong though. But perhaps there's a lighter way to do what you want to do?

Comment: Try using Smooth F1 instead of F1

Comment: or you can bake the voronoi, blur it a bit and convert to b&w, and use it as the image of your displacement

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This example uses another Voronoi Texture node for the Displacement Node's Height input socket, identical to the first Voronoi Texture node except for the Feature control being set to Smooth F1.  A Color Ramp provides some control for the effect but is otherwise unnecessary.  Please note I've used the same level of Subdivision as you did in your ask, less is feasible but not as smooth.

Generalizing past this example, instead of using a hard-edged map or procedural texture for displacement, it's usually better to use soft and then tighten it with a Color Ramp.

[image]